# How to set VM arguments to Tomcat instance

Tags: java, linux, shell, tomcat, jvm

I want to add the argument -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError because my Java application is suffering from java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space - error. My goal is to get the heapdump when the application crashes and then analyze the file with Eclipse MAT.

The Java application is running on a linux server where I only have a shell access. I am using Tomcat 9.

Based on a few tutorials, the operation should be quite simple:

1. locate $CATALINA_HOME
2. edit setenv.sh
3. add something like: CATALINA_OPTS="${CATALINA_OPTS} -Dparam=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
4. restart Tomcat and you are set!

But because the directory structures are always different, **I just can't locate that catalina folder** or maybe I just don't have it, is that even possible?

Here is what ls brings up in root:

```
adminhome
backup
bin -> usr/bin
boot
dev
etc
home
lib -> usr/lib
lib64 -> usr/lib64
lost+found
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin -> usr/sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
```

The Java Application (war) runs in var/lib/tomcat9/webapps

**EDIT: SOME PROGRESS!**

Okay so I think I've found the catalina home folder: /usr/share/tomcat9/
but there are no config files or scripts. The ls -l gives these directories:

```
bin
/etc/tomcat9
conf -> /etc/tomcat9
/usr/share/java/tomcat9
/var/log/tomcat9
/var/cache/tomcat9/temp
webapps -> /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps
work -> /var/cache/tomcat9/work
```

the application should already have a few VM arguments, so can they be elsewhere than in the catalina home or why there is no setenv.sh?

Comment: Do `ps -ef|grep -i java`.  Find your tomcat process in there.  You will see the different directories used.

Comment: @Nic3500 this commands gives this: $ ps -ef|grep -i java
tomcat    1106     1  0 Nov16 ?        00:07:28 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -classpath /usr/share/tomcat9/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat9/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat9 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat9 -Djava.endorsed.dirs= -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat9/temp -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat9/conf/logging.properties.

Does this mean that my catalina_home is at /usr/share/tomcat9 ? theres no configuration files, let alone scripts.

Comment: run `echo $CATALINA_HOME`

Comment: @DoNhuVy this prints nothing

Comment: From the result, you can see that Tomcat is installed under /usr/share/tomcat9/bin.  setenv.sh should be in that directory as well for you to edit.

Comment: @Nic3500 I have now created setenv.sh to that location, but when I restart tomcat, the logs do not mention about the arguments I set. Do I have to run the script or do something else before restarting tomcat?

Comment: I would expect setenv.sh to already exist somewhere around `/usr/share/tomcat9/`.  You could run `find /usr/share/tomcat9 -name setenv.sh -print` to see where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04 with tomcat9 service then create `/usr/share/tomcat9/bin/setenv.sh` file and put the configuration here to increase memory heap.

```
cat /usr/share/tomcat9/bin/setenv.sh 
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m"
```